# Adjacent TextView Overlaps in Android Relative Layout as TextView grows with Text, How to Fix this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have the layout as given below, in which I have two relative layouts as relativeLayout1 and relativeLayout2.

RelativeLayout1 contains RelativeLayout2 and the textview tvThree.
RelativeLayout2 contains two text views as tvOne and tvTwo.

Now the problem is if tvOne grows with the text then it is overlapping tvTwo. I want to make tvTwo move till the end of relativeLayout2 and then it should stop with tvOne at the left side.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ChatFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tvThree"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOne"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="TextView1"/>

            <TextView
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:id="@+id/tvTwo"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView2"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvThree"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView3"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Visual Representation]

Comment: i believe that a picture of what you are trying to say would be much more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Give them weight, or better way to achieve is put them horizontal linear layout and put layout weight  in linear layout 2 and give weight to each text view 1 each. If necessary I can paste the code.

Comment: I want the textview tvOne to grow according to text size but up to the ceratin limit so that it's adjacent textview tvTwo ould be visible. I want to do it without assigning weight.

Comment: the 2nd textview will also display some text.  You can do so by changing weight of one by 2, and is there any video or gif as what exactly you want to achieve.